# Make PHP's bc round instead of truncate?

Tags: php, bc

I'd like `bcadd(4.9,3)` to return `8` rather than `7`.  I'm using an example without lots of decimal places here, but the basic idea (that I want to round, rather than truncate) still stands. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`bcadd` lets you specify precision (and `bcscale`).  You can change it to `bcadd(4.9,3,$some_huge_number)` if you have a decimal max .. then you can just use `round()`.